# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when i try accessing mysql remotely

Tags: php, android, mysql, server

I am building an android application and want to store user credentials in a table using mysql. I have a server located elsewhere and have created the tables and configured everything as needed.

Here is the php file that connects to the mysql database:

```
<?php

$db_name="mydbname";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="mypassword";
$server_name="localhost";

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_user, $db_name);
if(!$con){
    echo "Connection error...".mysqli_connect_error();

}
else{
    echo "Successful";
}

?>
```

When I execute this locally on my system at home (with the necessary changes, of course) it works perfectly and returns 'Successful'. Even on running the android application it updates the tables as expected.

But when I try executing the above php script remotely on my server it says:

> "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

even though I can use mysql from home on a terminal. The server is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: localhost is no longer your home computer on a remote server...  of course this doesn't work.  Are you trying to connect to your home database server or the remote server's database server?  Do you have the same credentials for both?

Comment: please check MySQL user id, password  and IP address

Comment: @Devon i did try changing localhost to my server's IP address. it gave me the same error. am i doing something wrong? is there something else i have to put in the server_name field? also, i have the credentials for both databases. works fine with home server but denies access in the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Go to MySQL ® Databases , Create a similar name for the database and username.

like this :

**Database** : myhost_mydbname

**Username** : myhost_mydbname

**NextStep** : Select ALL PRIVILEGES on the **Add User To Database** [Add Button] !
And then, Try this :

```php
$db_name="myhost_mydbname";
$mysql_user="myhost_mydbname";
$mysql_pass="mypassword";
$server_name="localhost";
```

I hope this method will help you !

Answer (score -1):

If you're on an app which would be on a different device you can't use "localhost" as your host. As localhost refers to the current host you're on which in this case would be your android device.

If you're on the same network as the ubuntu server or if it has a publicly accessible ip you can give its ip address as host. (Which you can figure out by running `ifconfig` on your ubuntu server).

But I doubt your root account will be accesible from anywhere else but localhost so I suggest you create a new user account by running
`CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

And use those credentials to login.